# How to resave image without borders in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I am just want to show and then save the same image on plot but got borders.

```
import numpy as np
import skimage.io
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fileName = "1.jpg"
image=mpimg.imread(fileName)
height, width = image.shape[:2]

my_dpi = 96 / 2
fg, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(1080/my_dpi, 1920/my_dpi), dpi=my_dpi)
ax.set_ylim(height, 0)
ax.set_xlim(0, width)
ax.axis('off')
ax.imshow(image.astype(np.uint8))
plt.savefig("res.png")
```

Source image:

[image: original image]

Result image after resaving:
[image: Result image after resaving]
How to remove the borders and make the result image be the same as original without borders?